# Dual boot Ubuntu - macOS Issue

Tags: startup, unix, dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu in dual boot on my Mac without using rEFInd. Initially everything worked fine, I could access both systems. Later, in an attempt to remove Ubuntu, I deleted a partition I had created for swap and since then GRUB has replaced the Mac's boot loader. So now I can only access Ubuntu. I would like to be able to access macOS again without losing any data. How can I do that?

The GParted image shown below was taken while booted to Ubuntu.

[image: Current situation]

### Update

Thanks to internet recovery, I was able to open the Terminal. Below is the result.

[image]

Comment: When you boot pushing the alt key have you the Mac os X choice?

Comment: No, this is the problem

Comment: Can you create a install USB KEY of your Mac os x version, then boot with it an from the terminal (on top menu/Utility give the results of command `diskutil list internal` ?

Comment: @Jean_JD has the right idea. However, posting the output from `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` from an Ubuntu Terminal application window would be quicker and simpler to implement. In either case, the commands will not change your Mac. The idea is just to see what is in the GUID partition table (GPT).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `diskutil` command or the Disk Utility application is applied to a drive which has Linux type partitions, the [partition type GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs) stored in the GUID Partition Table (GPT) for a macOS partition is often changed to `FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF`. The GParted image you posted in your question will not show this change. In other words, if the partition type GUID for `/dev/sda2` had been changed from `7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC` to `FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF`, then the file system shown in GParted will still remain `apfs`. This is because GParted looks at the content of the partition to determine the filesystem and not at the partition type GUID. However, the Mac firmware (Mac Startup Manager) does look at the partition type GUID when displaying possible operating systems to boot from.

One possible way to determine, if the partition type GUID for `/dev/sda2` is `7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC`, is to view the output from the command shown below. This command needs to be entered in an Ubuntu Terminal application window. (From the Ubuntu desktop, press the key combination <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a Terminal application window.)

```
sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda
```

You should see the code `AF0A`. If you see code `FFFF` then partition type GUID is probably `FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF`. If necessary, you can change the partition type GUID back to `7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC` by entering the command and interactive input shown below. Here I assume number for this partition is `2`. If not, then make the appropriate substitution below.

```
sudo gdisk /dev/sda
t
2
AF0A
w
y
```

> Note: The `gdisk` command uses 4 character codes to represent the much longer partition type GUIDs.

### A Clarification Regarding the Question

In your question you state *"GRUB has replaced the Mac's boot loader"*. Actually, this is impossible. The Mac boot loader is implemented in firmware. In your case, the Macs boot loader is boot loading GRUB and then GRUB is boot loading Ubuntu.

Comment: thank you ! I was able to fix it. You saved me :)

Comment: If you accept my answer, then a green check mark will appear next to my answer. This will show others a solution was found to your question.